# How to use conditions in Google Sheet when using mentions

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that consists of a list of names and need to count the number of times each name appears in the list. Unfortunately, the names have all been created using "mentions" (prepended with @, such as "@Pete Scott"), and that seems to be breaking the formula.

=COUNTIF(D$2:D,"=@Pete Scott") does not work, nor does =COUNTIF(D$2:D,"=Pete Scott), nor does looking in a separate cell containing a matching mention.

Here's an illustration of the issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jovn9OV5qvH1_SiejjluHah01WnetSHajlh5iSU7X54/edit?usp=sharing

Any insight into getting this to work would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  For example, are you trying to catch non-chip entries? What is the source and purpose of the manually entered lookup values? Could they (should they) be dynamically generated?

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```
=QUERY(D:D, "Select D, Count(D) 
   where D is not Null Group by D",1)
```

## COUNTIF vs. QUERY

I have included two array formulas that both return a unique list of values from Column D as well as the counts.

1. **COUNTIF**
   Sees a difference between a smart chip name and a text string
2. **QUERY**
   Doesn't differentiate between the two different types of names.

## COUNTIF

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
   rng,TOCOL(D2:D,1),
   unq,UNIQUE(rng), 
   {unq, COUNTIF(rng,unq)}))
```

1. Using an infinite range `D2:D` means any future data you add to column D will be included in the formula.
2. TOCOL is used because setting its `ignore` argument to `1` skips blank rows in the range.
3. The LET function was used to store values so the calculations don't need to be repeated, but the same formula can be written without it:

   ```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(
     {UNIQUE(TOCOL(D2:D,1)),
      COUNTIF(TOCOL(D2:D,1),
        UNIQUE(TOCOL(D2:D,1)))})
   ```

## QUERY

The QUERY function would be my approach as it is well-suited to this type of task.

```
=QUERY(D:D, "Select D, Count(D) 
   where D is not Null Group by D",1)
```

##### Customize Column Label

QUERY allows including labels and, in the case of calculated columns such as `COUNT(D)`, it will return a label even if you don't specify that you have a label row.  You can customize or remove them using the `label` argument.  For example,

1. Use the existing label for column 1, but specify a custom label for column 2:

   ```
   =QUERY(D:D, "Select D, Count(D) 
      where D is not Null Group by D
      Label Count(D) 'Count'",1)
   ```
2. Don't include any labels for either column:

   ```
   =QUERY(D2:D, "Select D, Count(D) 
      where D is not Null Group by D
      Label Count(D) ''",0)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the event both the keys and data contain a mix of `@mention` chips and plain text values that look the same, a simple `countif()` will not get all occurrences, because a chip cannot be compared to a plain text value directly.

One way to work around that is to use `query()` as Blindspots shows. This function lets can aggregate the data into a result table without using a separate column for keys.

Another way is to convert all values to text before comparison, like this:

```
=arrayformula(countif(to_text(D$2:D), to_text(A2)))
```

Yet another way is to access the name in a `@mention` chip through its `.name` property. Properties can only be read from references and not from values, and they error out when a reference does not actually contain a chip. If both the keys and the data may or may not contain chips, extra logic is needed to check the value type before comparison. It can be done like this:

```
=let( 
  keys, A2:A4, 
  data, D2:D, 
  clean_, lambda(data, 
     map(sequence(rows(data)), lambda(i, let( 
      d, index(data, i), 
      if(type(d) = 128, index(data, i).name, d) 
    ))) 
  ), 
  map(clean_(keys), lambda(k, countif(clean_(data), k))) 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah! One of my co-workers figured it out. Instead of using a conditional pointing directly at the cell containing the matching value (e.g. "="&A2), he used the range of cells to the left (e.g. A2:A4) and it all worked perfectly. I've added a tab to the sheet with the solution.